# What is the equivalent of TruncateDecimalsToScale in EF Core 5.0?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am migrating legacy Entity Framework 6.X Application to EF Core 5.0. In the application, we are using **TruncateDecimalsToScale= false** because we want decimal values to be rounded instead of truncated. I was wondering what the equivalent of TruncateDecimalsToScale in EF Core 5.0 is.

```
public class EFConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public EFConfiguration()
    {
        // We don't want decimal values to be truncated but rounded.
        SqlProviderServices.TruncateDecimalsToScale = false;
    }
}

[DbConfigurationType(typeof(EFConfiguration))]
public class MyAppContext : DbContext
{
...
}
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an equivalent.  You'll have to round the values yourself.

Comment: The code assumes that decimal values will be rounded by EF, which may not be the best assumption taken by developers many years ago, but without an equivalent to TruncateDecimalsToScale we are dead in our tracks.

Comment: What is the problem to define ValueConverter which do what you need?

Comment: ValueConverter is not a scalable solution because it is not future proof and we cannot force that future decimal fields are not truncated.

Comment: EF 6 by default truncates to scale before sending decimal values to the database but it also allows developers to override this behavior by setting TruncateDecimalsToScale=false which lets decimal values to be passed as-is to SQL Server where they are rounded [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlproviderservices.truncatedecimalstoscale?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=entity-framework-6.2.0#overloads).
IMO it is a fair ask to let the developer do the right thing based on their scenarios to either Round or Truncate decimal values at the DB level.

Comment: What prevents you from including an additional property in your DTO that performs this rounding function for you?

Comment: We have thousands of DTOs and it is not practical to inject rounding to every DTO. Our goal is to take this cross-cutting concern and abstract it at a centralized location. 
Do you know of any solution to round decimal at a centralized location for EF Core? Or is this feature on the roadmap for EF Core 6 or later?

Comment: So, then try `ValueConverterSelector`

Comment: Thanks @SvyatoslavDanyliv. Do you have an example of how to use ValueConverterSelector?

Comment: Sample implemnation is here https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore/blob/16be67a685256e824184cfe3cc6a304aed28ace1/Tests/LinqToDB.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Tests/ValueConversion/IdValueConverterSelector.cs#L7 then `optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<IValueConverterSelector, IdValueConverterSelector>()`

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite old question, but I solved a similar problem and fixed it using a custom convention that gives ValueConversion to all decimal properties of entities.

```
public class TruncateDecimalConvention : IModelFinalizingConvention
{
    public void ProcessModelFinalizing(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder, IConventionContext<IConventionModelBuilder> context)
    {
        var columnTypeRegex = new Regex(@"\s*\w+\s*\((?<precision>\d+),\s*(?<scale>\d+)\)\s*", RegexOptions.Compiled);

        var propertyWithConverters = modelBuilder.Metadata.GetEntityTypes()
            .SelectMany(entity =>
                entity.GetDeclaredProperties()
                    .Where(property => property.ClrType == typeof(decimal) || property.ClrType == typeof(decimal?))
                    .Where(property => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(property.GetColumnType()))
                    .Select(property =>
                    {
                        ValueConverter<decimal, decimal>? valueConverter = null;

                        var columnType = property.GetColumnType();
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(columnType)) {
                            var columnTypeMatch = columnTypeRegex.Match(columnType);
                            if (columnTypeMatch.Success)
                            {
                                var scale = int.Parse(columnTypeMatch.Groups["scale"].Value);
                                var num = (decimal)Math.Pow(10, scale);

                                valueConverter = new(x => decimal.Truncate(x * num) / num, x => x);
                            }
                        }
                        
                        return (property, valueConverter);
                    })
                    .Where(x => x.valueConverter != null)
            );

        foreach (var (decimalProperty, valueConverter) in propertyWithConverters) {
            decimalProperty.Builder.HasConversion(valueConverter);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in DbContext inject the convetion in method ConfigureConventions

```
protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
    base.ConfigureConventions(configurationBuilder);

    configurationBuilder.Conventions.Add(_ => new TruncateDecimalConvention());
}
```

Hope it helps to someone else.